# find first not repeating character

Tags: python

Problem:

Given a string s consisting of small English letters, find and return the first instance of a non-repeating character in it. If there is no such character, return '_'.

Example

For `s = "abacabad"`, the output should be
`firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) = 'c'`.

This is what I have so far, but it's too slow. How can I make the run time faster? Thanks.

```
def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):
    char = set(s)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s.count(s[i]) == 1:
            return s[i]
    return "_"
```

Comment: You need to iterate over `char` & not `range(len(s))` and check `if s.count(i) == 1`

Comment: A set is not ordered so iterating over char would not return the *first* character that occurs once. But it is possible to iterate over s directly (without range and len) or use an ordered set.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What do you mean by "too slow"? For short strings like your example `"abacabad"`, your implementation should be sufficiently fast. (I measured around 0.99 µs per call.) Are you interested in asymptotic worst-case behavior, a.k.a. big-O notation? (Your implementation's computational complexity scales squared w.r.t. input length, while linear complexity implementations are possible for the problem.)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the characters in linear time, and then filter the result in conjunction with [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), like this:

```
from collections import Counter


def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):
    counts = Counter(s)
    return next((ch for ch in s if counts[ch] < 2), "_")


print(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("abacabad"))
```

**Output**

```
c
```

Or simply use a dictionary (no imports needed):

```
counts = {}
for ch in s:
    counts[ch] = counts.get(ch, 0) + 1

return next((ch for ch in s if counts[ch] < 2), "_")
```

Both approaches are linear in the length of the input string, your current approach is `O(k*s)` where `k` is the number of unique characters.