# Can't pass CodeSignal Hidden Tests

Tags: python

Given a string s consisting of small English letters, find and return the first instance of a non-repeating character in it. If there is no such character, return '_'.

This passes all tests, except for 3 hidden ones and cannot figure out what is happening-- I have tried creating custom tests and they all pass.

```
def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):
for i in s:
    if s.count(i) == 1:
        return i
return("_")
```

Comment: Perhaps your code is too slow? That algorithm will scan the list `len(s) * len(s) / 2` times, whereas a more efficient algorithm needs only `len(s) + len(s) / 2` on average.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find first not repeating character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64511632/find-first-not-repeating-character)

Comment: Can you show an example of a string where this doesn't give the required result?